Announcing a Pro Tempore election for 2024
Update on August 13, 2024:
This election has been canceled for now due to a lack of nominations (even after extending the nomination phase by one week). It is still a priority to bring on a new mod to this team, to allow the site to continue to be a functional space for this community.
Staff and the current mods will work together to reach out to community members who we would like to encourage to nominate themselves, and will then reschedule the election in the coming months. Alternatively, if you have any interest in potentially taking on a mod role, please comment on this post and we can follow up to answer any questions.
Stack Exchange sites can only continue on as long as there are users willing to step up and moderate, so please consider it!

Summary: elementary OS Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for a special election on July 30, 2024 to bring in 1 more moderator.
For full details of the process, see the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange. The timeline:

Starting on July 30, users can nominate themselves. Users can also ask questions on Meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the discussion and election tags.)

On August 6, if there are 2 or more candidates, the election will move into the voting phase. If not, we'll extend the nomination period for a week. If, at the end of that extension period, there are still fewer than 2 candidates, we'll simply appoint the candidate. (There's a small chance we'll need to remove a nomination.)

If the election moves into the voting phase, we'll announce the results on Meta on August 14 (or August 21, if we need to extend the nomination period).


If you have any questions about the process, please post them in an answer here.
